# MVC4 Razor WebGrid Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

I am trying to use WebGrid on my Razor views, but I am getting this error message :

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1978: Cannot use an expression of type 
'lambda expression' as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation
```

Here is the controller's code :

```
  var query = GetAll().ToList();
  ViewBag.grid = new WebGrid(students, rowsPerPage: 20);
  return View();
```

The View :

```
@{
    var grid = ViewBag.grid;
}
@grid.GetHtml("tblMain",
    columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Name", format: @<Text>Test</Text>)
        ))
```

I was able use webgrid on my controller and generate the HTML and render it in view, but because i need templates, so I tried to create the webgrid in view not controller. I searched the web, there are few samples in the same way, but I am still getting this error. I would appreciate any help or idea.

Answer (score 1):

As son as you put your WebGrid in ViewBag, it became a dynamic object and those do not support delegates represented as lambda expressions. Pass the data in ViewBag if you do not want to use a strongly typed view, but construct the grid in the View, or cast the grid to the proper type in the View.

Comment: Just something to keep in mind for the future: *You post good answers*, and you generally post a useful answer *here*, and only use links as additional reference. That is good. There is just one tiny thing to keep in mind for the future: According to the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion), each time you link to your own website/product/library/etc, you must disclose that fact. So for example, where you say "see this for more information", you could instead say, "See this article on my website for more information".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20225/discussion-between-andrew-barber-and-mike-brind)

Answer (score 0):

Casting the result from the ViewBag will change grid variable from a dynamic type to the proper type.  You should then be able to use it just like you have been.

```
@{
    var grid = (WebGrid)ViewBag.grid;
}
@grid.GetHtml("tblMain",
    columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Name", format: @<Text>Test</Text>)
        ))
```

Comment: That said, rendering the list of students as a grid is part of the presentation layer and should be done in the view, not the controller.  I would recommend sending the list of students to the view, and create whatever presentation you want in the view (in your case, the grid).